# How move sprite in Java 2d (swing) with keyboard?

Tags: 2d, java, input

I'm practicing some simple techniques with Java swing games, to learn the basics. Right now I'm practicing how to move a sprite... but it's not working! whhyyyy

Here is what I've come up with so far (**Main class**):

```
public class GraphicsPracticeDrawing extends JPanel implements Runnable{

private CoinSprite coin2;
private Thread animate;

private final int DELAY = 25;

public GraphicsPracticeDrawing(){
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    this.addKeyListener(new InputHandler());

    Initialize();
    animate = new Thread(this);
    animate.start();
}

public void Initialize(){
    coin2 = new CoinSprite("images/coin.gif", 25, 25);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.drawImage(coin2.getImage(), coin2.getX(), coin2.getY(), null);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    long beforeTime, timeDiff, sleep;

    beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(true){
        coin2.move2(); //move the 2nd coin based on the inputHandler
        repaint();

        timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
        sleep = DELAY - timeDiff;

        if(sleep < 0)
            sleep = 2;

        try{
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Animation interrupted!");
        }

        beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}

/*
 * create a inner class to handle key inputs via the CoinSprite class
 */
private class InputHandler extends KeyAdapter{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        coin2.keyPressed(e);
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        coin2.keyReleased(e);
    }
}
```

}

and for my **CoinSprite class**:

```
public class CoinSprite {

private BufferedImage img;
private int speedKeyX, speedKeyY;

public CoinSprite(){ }

public CoinSprite(String fileLoc, int x, int y){
    try{
        this.img = ImageIO.read(new File(fileLoc));
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Can't load file!");
    }

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

/*
 * move the sprite based on key inputs
 */
public void move2() {
    this.x += this.speedKeyX;
    this.y += this.speedKeyY;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        speedKeyX = -1; //when move is, called change the speed
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        speedKeyX = 1;
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        speedKeyX = 0;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        speedKeyX = 0;
    }
}

//GETTERS
public BufferedImage getImage(){ return this.img; }
public int getX(){ return this.x; }
public int getY(){ return this.y; }

//SETTERS
public void setX(int x){ this.x = x; }
public void setY(int y){ this.y = y; }
```

}

When I run the game and press left and right the sprite wont move! I don't know why...

Comment: I would breakpoint the keyPressed procedure in the coin class and inspect the speedKeyX variable. Is it getting set properly? is your move2() getting called (another breakpoint)  ... as for your checks e.getKeyCode() == KeyEnent.VK_LEFT) i would use an int and capture that once on entering the keyPressesd function vs. continuing to call getKeycode (i.e. int key = e.getKeyCode(); and then ask if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) // etc ... also is it possible to go both right and left at once? Your code thinks so, if (left condition) { ... } else if (right condition) { ... } makes more sense for

Comment: You should ask programming questions like this on http://StackOverflow.com instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, I needed to set my JPanel to focusable() in order to handle input.

In my constructor I added:

```
this.setFocusable(true);
```

and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void run() {
    long beforeTime, timeDiff, sleep;

    beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(true){
        coin2.move2(); //move the 2nd coin based on the inputHandler
        repaint();

        timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
        sleep = DELAY - timeDiff;

        if(sleep < 0)
            sleep = 2;

        try{
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Animation interrupted!");
        }

        beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}

/*
 * create a inner class to handle key inputs via the CoinSprite class
 */
private class InputHandler extends KeyAdapter{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        coin2.keyPressed(e);
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        coin2.keyReleased(e);
    }
}



public class CoinSprite {

private BufferedImage img;
private int speedKeyX, speedKeyY;

public CoinSprite(){ }

public CoinSprite(String fileLoc, int x, int y){
    try{
        this.img = ImageIO.read(new File(fileLoc));
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Can't load file!");
    }

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

/*
 * move the sprite based on key inputs
 */
public void move2() {
    this.x += this.speedKeyX;
    this.y += this.speedKeyY;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        speedKeyX = -1; //when move is, called change the speed
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        speedKeyX = 1;
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        speedKeyX = 0;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        speedKeyX = 0;
    }
}

//GETTERS
public BufferedImage getImage(){ return this.img; }
public int getX(){ return this.x; }
public int getY(){ return this.y; }

//SETTERS
public void setX(int x){ this.x = x; }
public void setY(int y){ this.y = y; }

this.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: Could you describe your method/intent? A code dump isn't a great answer.